# Атака buffer overflow

Tags: безопасность, ос, сегментация

Работает ли атака buffer overflow на современных ос? Ведь сейчас,  когда программы исполняются в защищенном режиме,  память разбита на сегменты кода,  данных и стека. И программа имеет право исполнять только сегмент кода. При этом прав на запись в сегмент кода у нее нет. Получается процессор не позволит программе исполнить инструкцию,  которая находится в сегменте стека.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ведь сейчас, когда программы исполняются в защищенном режиме ...

Атака на переполнение буфера направлена не на саму операционную систему, а на программы и то, как они работают со своими данными.

> ... память разбита на сегменты кода, данных и стека ...

Уже нет. Сегментная модель памяти ушла окончательно и бесповоротно в x64-процессорах. Единственное, что осталось — плоская модель памяти и страничная виртуализация.

> При этом прав на запись в сегмент кода у нее нет.

Верно. Однако атаки на переполнение буфера направлены не на код, а на перезапись данных, лежащих в стеке. Это могут быть значения локальных переменных, либо адрес возврата (который можно изменить на, например, адрес функции в своей библиотеке-плагине).

> Получается процессор не позволит программе исполнить инструкцию, которая находится в сегменте стека.

А процессор никогда и не исполнял код в *сегменте* стека. Для этого этот процессор надо как-то заставить выполнить прыжок в *область памяти*, занимаемую стеком. Раньше это можно было с некоторой долей везения проделать через запись поверх адреса возврата, но сейчас да, процессор выбросит исключение нарушения  страничной защиты.